# Is there an elegant way to get fist two consecutive characters from a String until fist digit occurrence

Tags: java, string

I want to get the fist two characters (not digits) from a String until the first digit occurance. String may be any and would contains digits too. I just have to care first two indexes only. Bit tricky part is let say the second index contains a digit, then only the first character need to consider.

```
Examples:

abcd -> ab
a -> a
a0cd -> a
0bcd -> null
-123 -> null
```

Below is how I wrote this function in java. Is there any other elegant way to do this? Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    public static String getFirstTwoCharBeforeDigit(String s) {
        if(null==s||s.length()==0) return null;
        int cropIndex=Math.min(s.length(), 2);      
        if(!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0))) return null;
        if(cropIndex>1 && !Character.isLetter(s.charAt(1))) --cropIndex;

        return s.substring(0,cropIndex);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getFirstTwoCharBeforeDigit("Az-a0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You reach `s.charAt(1) ` for strings with length 1, causing an exception

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks @SOlsson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the use of *regular expressions* as described in the API of the `Pattern` class.

```
"^[a-z]{1,2}"
```

---

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ConsecutiveCharsTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        //@formatter:off
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {"abcd", "ab" },
            {"a", "a" },
            {"a0bc", "a" },
            {"0bcd", null },
            {"-123", null },
        });
        //@formatter:on
    }

    private final String input;
    private final String expected;

    public ConsecutiveCharsTest(String input, String expected) {
        super();
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{1,2}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            assertEquals(input, expected, matcher.group());
        } else {
            assertNull("no Match expected", expected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The suggested pattern only works for a restricted subset of English. To allow any letters one should use \p{IsAlphabetic} rather than [a-z].
To be even more precise, the question asks for any characters not a digit. That would be \D.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne The pattern matches the samples. And the YAGNI-Principle tells that this is enough... Also `\D` would fail because it would match the `-`in the last sample.

Comment: You are right, but when the samples do not match the specs who is to say which of them is to be adhered to?

Comment: That depends on whether the samples where written to explain the specs or the specs were written to describe the samples. It is much better when the specs and the samples agree. According to the plain text of the question the third sample is wrong. It says characters, not letters.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work (thank you Timothy):

```
private static final java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{1,2}");

private static String getFirstTwoChars(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(0) : null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `"^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}"` instead of `"^[a-z]{1,2}"`

Answer (score 1):

I think that using `RegExp` for this simple task is **too heavy**, because lot's of additional objects are created behind the scene. My solution is less readable, but it has better performance and minimal additional memory objects creation:

```
public static String getFirstTwoCharBeforeDigit(String str) {
    return str != null && !str.isEmpty() ? Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(0)) ? str.substring(0, str.length() > 1 && Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(1)) ? 2 : 1) : null : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more alternative:

```
public static String getFirstTwoCharBeforeDigit(String str) {
    String firstTwo = str.substring(0,Math.min(str.length(), 2)).replaceAll("\\d*$", "");
    return firstTwo.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter) && !firstTwo.isEmpty()? 
           firstTwo:
           null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!